# Evernote API in Unity3D

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, evernote, vuforia

Since I haven't got any response on the Unity3d or Evernote forums, I'll try it here.

The last year I have worked a lot with Unity3D, mostly because the good integration with the Vuforia Augmented Reality library and the fact that publishing for multiple platforms is a piece of cake.

Now I want to show notes in an AR setting and am looking at the Evernote API for this. I couldn't find anything about using this with Unity, I can see why this is not the most common combination.

My question is: do you think I can access the Evernote API through Unity? If so, how should I do this? Or is it for this purpose perhaps wiser to make (parts of) the application with Eclipse/xCode?

Hope to hear from you!

Link to Evernote API: http://dev.evernote.com/doc/

Answer (score 1):

The Evernote API has a C# SDK which you should be able to call through Unity. In terms of how to do it, you will probably need to download the SDK and follow the instructions yourself. Their [github](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-csharp) seems like a good starting point.

One thing to note is that Unity's .Net library for mobile clients are quite limited and with webplayer you will need to deal with sandbox security issues. But start with the standalone build first and see how you go